# Unable to change dom element value in ngOnInit with directive applied

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am using a custom directive to format percentage values. Everything works as expected except I am unable to load the formatted value of the element on which I applied the directive on ngOnInit. It works fine if there is no [(ngModel)] on that element. I have also tried with other lifecycle hooks like ngAfterViewInit but it wont work. It works on ngAfterViewChecked or ngDoCheck but then the directive behaves incorrectly while entering a value in the input element.

Please refer the sample [percent-directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/percent-directive-demo-ipmvno?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpercent.directive.ts)

```
<!-- in app.component.html -->
<input type="text" appPercent [digit]="3" [decimals]="2" 
  [(ngModel)]="profitPercent">
```

```
// in percent.directive.ts
ngOnInit(){
    let decimalZeroes = "0".repeat(this.decimals);
    let uiValue: string = `0.${decimalZeroes}`;
    let onBlurValue: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let parsedValue: number =  parseFloat(onBlurValue);

    if (parsedValue>100.0) {
      uiValue = `100.${decimalZeroes}`;
    } else if(!isNaN(parsedValue)){
      // this.model.update.emit(parsedValue); // this does not work
      uiValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(parsedValue,'1.'+ this.decimals + '-' + this.decimals);
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.value = uiValue + '%';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with following steps :

- removed NgModel as a provider
- remove NgModel from constructor to the benefit of NgControl
- moved onInit logic inside the the subscription on valueChanges

```js
constructor(control: NgControl) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      let decimalZeroes = "0".repeat(this.decimals);
      let uiValue: string = `0.${decimalZeroes}`;
      let onBlurValue: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      let parsedValue: number =  parseFloat(onBlurValue);

      if (parsedValue>100.0) {
        uiValue = `100.${decimalZeroes}`;
      } else if(!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
        uiValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(parsedValue,'1.'+ this.decimals + '-' + this.decimals);
      }
      this.el.nativeElement.value = uiValue + '%';
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks, it displays the formatted value onInit, however unable to edit the value while typing. The valueChanges gets called every time the DOM value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution:
In my ngOnInit I check if the control is pristine and only then the formatting is active. Thereafter on blur I mark the control pristine again. Here's the Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/percent-directive-demo-ipmvno?file=src/app/percent.directive.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    let toPercent: any;
    let percentStr: string;

    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(that.model.control.pristine);
        if (that.model.control.pristine && value) {
            toPercent = value;
            let formattedValue = that.decimalPipe.transform(
                    toPercent,
`1.${that.decimals}-${that.decimals}`);
            percentStr = `${toPercent}%`;
            that.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(percentStr);
        }
    });
}

 @ HostListener("blur")
onBlur() {
    let decimalZeroes = "0".repeat(this.decimals);
    let uiValue: string = `0.${decimalZeroes}`;
    let onBlurValue: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let parsedValue: number = parseFloat(onBlurValue);

    if (!this.greaterThan100 && parsedValue > 100.0) {
        uiValue = `100.${decimalZeroes}`;
    } else if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
        // this.model.update.emit(parsedValue);
        uiValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(
                parsedValue,
                "1." + this.decimals + "-" + this.decimals);
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.value = uiValue + "%";
    this.model.control.markAsPristine();
}
```